# Yii2 Перезапись свойств объекта 2ого уровня

Tags: php, yii2

Что-то я недопонимаю в следующем:

```
        // в POST $model->name пришло любое значение
        $model->name = 'test';
        print_r($model->name); // Вывод 'test'
        // в POST $model->content['image'] пришло пустое значение
        $model->content['image'] = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'content[image]');
        // или $model->content['image'] = 'любойтекст';
        print_r($model->content['image']); // Вывод пустой
```

На `rules` можно не ориентироваться

В поле `content` я храню различные значения, которые не требуются для построения запросов к базе, это могут быть мета-теги, изображения. Потом в BeforeSave я массив $this->content перекодирую в JSON и добавляю в базу.

Как видно из кода выше, я просто не могу переназначить любой элемент массива $model->content, но могу переназначить любое свойство $model только первого уровня

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел способ

```
$content = $model->content;
$content['image'] = 'bla-bla-bla';
$model->content = $content;
```

Проблема в __get и __set родителей, видимо сеттер некорректно работает со свойствами 2ого уровня

Comment: за что минус интересно

Comment: наверное за ввод в заблуждение, что "__get и __set  работают только с первым уровнем свойств" - это не так

Comment: @Blacknife На примере кода в вопросе, покажите, что я заблуждаюсь, в сеттере. Или объясните, почему `$content = $model->content;
$content['anykey'] = 'bla-bla-bla';
$model->content = $content; echo $model->content['anykey']; // bla-bla-bla` работает, а `$model->content['anykey'] = 'bla-bla-bla'; echo $model->content['anykey'];  // ---` нет

Answer (score -2):

Ну вам ничего не пришло, вот оно и пустое. Идем в код и смотрим что возвращает getInstance https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UploadedFile.php#L110 Если файл пришел(content[image] должен быть именно файлом), то возвращает объект UploadedFile иначе null.

```
var_dump($model->content['image']);//null
```

Comment: Перечитайте внимательно код